# ThreadPoolTimer not working

Tags: c++-cx, uwp

I want to write code that executes periodically so a bit of searching seems to suggest that [ThreadPoolTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.threadpooltimer.aspx) suits my need. Here is my attempt to implement it:

```c
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    // Timer code
    TimeSpan period;
    period.Duration = 100000000000; // 1 second
    ThreadPoolTimer::CreatePeriodicTimer(ref new TimerElapsedHandler(this, &MainPage::TestTimer), period);
}

// Dummy method to test timer
void MainPage::TestTimer(Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPoolTimer^ timer)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"Timer triggered\n");
}
```

My expectation is that it prints "Timer triggered" every second. But nothing is printed out in my case. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TimeSpan seems to be incorrect. I just tried the following code to produce a 1 second timer.

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TimeSpan period;
    period.Duration = 10000000; // 1 second
    ThreadPoolTimer::CreatePeriodicTimer(ref new TimerElapsedHandler(this, &MainPage::TestTimer), period);
}

void MainPage::TestTimer(Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPoolTimer^ timer)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"Timer triggered\n");
}
```

I believe your code was producing a 10000 second timer.

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thank you very much. I followed the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967916.aspx) so blindly: it says that **This amount of time is specified in ticks (100-nanosecond units) using the Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan structure.** I put 100,000,000,000 as if counted in nanoseconds while it should be 1,000,000,000 / 100 = 10,000,000.

Comment: Yes, TimeSpan is the number of 100 nanosecond units, or 10^-7 seconds. So you need seven zeros to get one second.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Why does the C++/CX TimeSpan object use 100 nanoseconds instead of the more standard milliseconds? I'd imagine a lot of developers will run into problems with this

Comment: It's the standard unit used by various Windows APIs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx